# Should I apply to a job where the requested area of specialization is my area of competency?

Tags: job-search, faculty-application

There are some job ads in my job search where the school is seeking someone with an area of specialization (AOS) in "Bioethics/Biomedical Ethics or Environmental Ethics", and with an area of competency (AOC) in "Early Modern Philosophy, Non-Western Philosophy, Political Philosophy, Philosophy of Race, Feminist Philosophy, Environmental Philosophy, and/or 20th Century Continental".

This almost matches my AOC and AOS, except they are switched.
My AOS is Political Philosophy and Ethics (normative & applied)
and my AOC is 19th & 20th Century Continental Philosophy, Philosophy of Race, Environmental Ethics, Biomedical Ethics.

Is it worth my time to apply to jobs like this (I'm sure I will encounter more) where my Area of Specialization is one of their requested Areas of Competencies and/or where the requested Area of Specialization is my Area of Competency?

Comment: Others will, so why should you miss out...

Answer (score 1):

I would say look at the other aspects of the job (location, pay and benefits, company spirit, tasks and teams you would be a part of) and if all of that fits you could make an excellent applicant. Don't be too narrow in your search as many jobs change over time or people end up doing things not strictly related to their training.

If the job looks good, don't be scared about not perfectly fitting their profile.